# Order - OrderDetail Getting a resultset without using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a basic schema that is something like below

```
OrderTable
Id int

1
2

OrderDetailTable
Id int - OrderId int

1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        2
6        2
7        2
```

I want to get a table that is

```
OrderOrderDetailCombinationTable
Order int - OrderDetails varchar(100)
```

Example

```
Order - OrderDetails
1       1,2,3,4
2       5,6,7
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c617b/2

I can get this result by using cursor but cursor has a performance penalty as I know so what can be the better way to get this result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c617b/12)**

```
SELECT o.orderid AS [Order],
    STUFF((   SELECT ',' +CAST( x.id as varchar(2) )
        FROM orderdetail x
        WHERE o.orderid = x.orderid
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),1,1,'') as OrderDetails
FROM [orderdetail] o
INNER JOIN [order] oo
ON oo.id = o.orderid
GROUP BY o.orderid
```

Result:

```
| ORDER | ORDERDETAILS |
------------------------
|     1 |      1,2,3,4 |
|     2 |        5,6,7 |
```