# sql concatenate multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation, distinct

I have designed a view in SQL Server 2008 that displays 2 columns of distinct data in this format:

```
Column1 Column2
A       Text1
B       Text2
B       Text3
C       Text4
D       Text5
D       Text6
D       Text7
E       Text8
```

What do I have to do to get the view to display only the distinct Column1 values with Column2 values concatenated like this:

```
Column1 Column2
A       Text1
B       Text2, Text3
C       Text4
D       Text5, Text6, Text7
E       Text8
```

If I use the code suggested in the answers you seem to be considering as duplicate to this question, then I get this kind of result:

```
Column1 Column2
A       Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8
B       Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8
C       Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8
D       Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8
E       Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8
```

Edit: The revised code from @techdo worked, many thanks.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + Column2
       FROM YourTable t2
        WHERE t2.Column1=t1.Column1
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS Column2
FROM
    YourTable t1
GROUP BY Column1
```

Check [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643660/order-orderdetail-getting-a-resultset-without-using-cursor) for more details.

Comment: this code returns all column2 values for each column1 row like this:
A Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8
B Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8
C Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,Text5,Text6,Text7,Text8

Comment: Add `where` condition on `Column1`. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: I only have the ONE table.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks techdo.
But it was slightly confusing using t1 and t2 since I only have 1 table.

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are alias names given for your table.